# Parent maven project gives errors while compiling with IDEA but modules compile without a problem

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

My problem is: When I run "mvn package" from the command line it compiles fine but when I rebuild the project in IntelliJ IDEA (2018.3.2) it gives hundreds of errors saying "blah blah package does not exist" or "cannot find symbol blah blah".

My Maven structure consists of a parent pom with 4 sub modules (let's say A, B, C, D) that reference the parent pom. Module A references B & C. B & C each reference D. The parent has packaging set to "pom" and the four modules have packaging set to "jar". I am using maven-dependency-plugin to pack B, C, D in to A's output.

This bit must be important: When I right click on any of the projects (A, B, C or D) in project explorer of IDEA and click rebuild, each builds without a problem. When I right click on the parent project and click rebuild (or simply press Ctrl+Shift+F9) I get those errors about packages or symbols not found. The source files giving the errors are under module A, which as I said by itself compiles without a problem.

On more thing: All the dependencies of module A are (naturally) defined under module A's pom. If I move the dependencies to parent pom, the problem disappears and everyone compiles fine but when I move the dependencies back to module A's pom, problems again.

I've no idea why module A compiles fine by itself and why parent pom tries to compile module A's source code.

I've looked to similar questions on stackoverflow about maven compiling without a problem but IDEA giving erros, tried reimporting, reindexing, invalidating caches. None of the proposed solutions fixed my problem.

Any sugesstions are welcome

Edit: Here are the pom.xml's I am using. (I can't get SO the render the project tag correctly, sorry)

pom's for modules B, C and D I believe are irrelevant at this stage because I realized this error occurs in a version of code where module A does not include the code that depends on modules B, C or D. Below are the pom.xml's that cause this error and modules B, C and D are out of the picture.

Also, using the maven bundled with Atlassian Plugin SDK which is Maven 3.2.1

Parent pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    
        tr.com.my-organization.sdlc.pom
        root-pom-atl
        3.1.0

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>tr.com.my-organization</groupId>
<artifactId>my-project-aggregator</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>2.1.0.1</version>
<modules>
    <module>moduleD</module>
    <module>moduleC</module>
    <module>moduleB</module>
    <module>moduleA</module>
</modules>
<name>My Project Aggregator POM</name>
<properties>
    <dep.amps.version>5.0.3</dep.amps.version>
    <dep.jira.version>7.0.0</dep.jira.version>
    <buildNumber>1</buildNumber>
    <pkg.build.javaVersion>1.8</pkg.build.javaVersion>
    <dep.httpclient.version>4.3.4</dep.httpclient.version>
    <dep.testkit.version>5.2.26</dep.testkit.version>
    <dep.servlet.version>2.4</dep.servlet.version>
    <dep.junit.version>4.10</dep.junit.version>
    <dep.javax.version>1.1.1</dep.javax.version>
    <dep.gson.version>2.3</dep.gson.version>
    <dep.slf4j.version>1.6.6</dep.slf4j.version>
    <dep.mockito.version>1.8.5</dep.mockito.version>
    <dep.template.version>1.3.1</dep.template.version>
    <dep.springosgi.version>1.1.3</dep.springosgi.version>
    <dep.springcontext.version>2.5.6.SEC02</dep.springcontext.version>
    <dep.ao.version>0.19.7</dep.ao.version>
    <dep.commons-lang.version>2.4</dep.commons-lang.version>
    <dep.jira-greenhopper.version>6.4.1</dep.jira-greenhopper.version>
    <upm.license.compatibility.version>2.0.1</upm.license.compatibility.version>
    <sal.api.version>2.4.0</sal.api.version>        
    <useFastdevCli>false</useFastdevCli>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>bamboo</id>
        <properties>
            <buildNumber>${bambooBuildNumber}</buildNumber>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

pom.xml for Module A

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    
        tr.com.my-organization
        my-project-aggregator
        2.1.0.1
        ../

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>moduleA</artifactId>
<packaging>atlassian-plugin</packaging>

<properties>
    <pkg.build.javaVersion>1.8</pkg.build.javaVersion>
    <dep.httpclient.version>4.3.4</dep.httpclient.version>
    <dep.testkit.version>5.2.26</dep.testkit.version>
    <dep.servlet.version>2.4</dep.servlet.version>
    <dep.junit.version>4.10</dep.junit.version>
    <dep.javax.version>1.1.1</dep.javax.version>
    <dep.gson.version>2.3</dep.gson.version>
    <dep.slf4j.version>1.6.6</dep.slf4j.version>
    <dep.mockito.version>1.8.5</dep.mockito.version>
    <dep.template.version>1.3.1</dep.template.version>
    <dep.springosgi.version>1.1.3</dep.springosgi.version>
    <dep.springcontext.version>2.5.6.SEC02</dep.springcontext.version>
    <dep.ao.version>0.19.7</dep.ao.version>
    <dep.commons-lang.version>2.4</dep.commons-lang.version>
    <dep.jira-greenhopper.version>6.4.1</dep.jira-greenhopper.version>
    <upm.license.compatibility.version>2.0.1</upm.license.compatibility.version>
    <sal.api.version>2.4.0</sal.api.version>
    <useFastdevCli>false</useFastdevCli>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-api</artifactId>
        <version>${dep.jira.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-osgi-core</artifactId>
        <version>${dep.springosgi.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${dep.springcontext.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${dep.junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>atlassian-plugins-osgi-testrunner</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>${dep.javax.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2-atlassian-1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${dep.servlet.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${dep.slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>${dep.httpclient.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>${dep.mockito.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.templaterenderer</groupId>
        <artifactId>atlassian-template-renderer-api</artifactId>
        <version>${dep.template.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>${dep.commons-lang.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-greenhopper-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${dep.jira-greenhopper.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.activeobjects</groupId>
        <artifactId>activeobjects-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${dep.ao.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.upm</groupId>
        <artifactId>licensing-api</artifactId>
        <version>${upm.license.compatibility.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.upm</groupId>
        <artifactId>upm-api</artifactId>
        <version>${upm.license.compatibility.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.sal</groupId>
        <artifactId>sal-api</artifactId>
        <version>${sal.api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jira-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${dep.amps.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <productVersion>${dep.jira.version}</productVersion>
                <productDataVersion>${dep.jira.version}</productDataVersion>
                <enableQuickReload>true</enableQuickReload>
                <enableFastdev>false</enableFastdev>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-storage-plugin</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                        <includeArtifactIds>plugin-license-storage-plugin</includeArtifactIds>
                        <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: are you using `<dependencyManagement>` in your parent pom?

Comment: Irrespective of the IDE, this may have to do with the bundled maven that arrives with the IDE. Have you tried changing from the default to the Maven installed on your computer?

Comment: Can you post the pom's you're using?